# PHP string to decimal with .00

Tags: php, numbers

so I am trying to achieve this
I have decimal `1.00` Which when i convert to float becomes `1.0`. So my question is how can i save the last zero and at the same time to be float not a string if i use `number_format(1.0,2)` it becomes `"1.00"` Which is string but i need to be decimal with the last zero. This is what i tried so far

```
<?php

$decimal = "1.0";
$decimalToFloat = floatval($decimal) // It becomes 1.0
$decimalToFloat = number_format($decimal,2) // It becomes "1.00" !!! String not a float !!!
// The result which i want is 1.00 not "1.00"
```

Comment: Why does the extra 0 matter unless you are dealing with it as a string (such as printing it out in a report or something)?    1 === 1.0  === 1.00  === 1.0000000  are virtually computationally identical.  BTW:..  $decimal = "1.0" is going to make PHP treat $decimal as a STRING.

Comment: I know, it's the same but i have to send it in this format to Rest API. For instance in C# is possible

Comment: you do DO need to deal with it as a string  of   1.00    is the problem that you are ended up with quotes around it via some middleware or other code?  By middlware I'm asking   how are you expressing this to the REST API?  Are you using some package, writing to STDout..  a stream..   how are you interacting with the API and why does it care if the float looks like:   1.0  ?    Sorry, you're question doen't really have enough context to make sense to me.

Comment: @DDeMartini Man... i did't understand you at all, where you saw middleware ? Look at my previous comment

Comment: OK forget about the term middleware.   There is not enough code there to explain how your are OUTPUTTING the value (echo, print, file_write, carrier pigeon?), and also if the issue youre having is the method you're using to express the data is treating 1.0 as a string because you're treating it as a string (for example, if you are posting the data as JSON,  JSON cares about the data type)

Answer (score 2):

Let me start by saying that this is an **[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)**, as you don't **need** to convert from a string to an integer in PHP, as PHP will coerce the type for you automatically.

In addition to this, there is no need to specify the number of places on a decimal, as `1` is exactly equal to `1.0`, and `1.0` is exactly equal to `1.00`. In fact, forcibly casting the string showcases that PHP will automatically trim the decimal places:

```
$decimal = "1.0";
echo number_format((float)$decimal, 2, '.', '');  // "1.00" (string)
echo (int)number_format((float)$decimal, 2, '.', ''); // 1 (int)
echo (float)number_format((float)$decimal, 2, '.', ''); // 1 (float)
```

It is impossible to showcase an `int` or `float` with decimal places comprised purely of zeros in PHP. Though you do not need to do this; you can simply use the whole numbers instead:

```
echo 1 + 1.01; // 2.01 (float)
```

Hope this helps! :)